# Divide all numeric columns by a common factor; different factor per different groups of rows

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr, purrr

I want to divide all numeric columns by a common factor, using a different factor in each subset of rows.

A representative example is with the `iris` dataset, if I wanted to divide all numeric columns for each `Species` by a different factor eg

1. Setosa by 1
2. Versicolor by 10
3. Virginica by 100

Tried split then combine - provide list of factors; split `iris` dataset list of dataframes by group, map over both inputs, then recombine - but I can't get the map right

```
map_dfr(list(1,10,100), ~
              iris %>% 
              group_split(Species) %>% 
              mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~x / .x)))

Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('vctrs_list_of', 'vctrs_vctr', 'list')"
```

Or using `map2` for two list inputs:

```
map2(x = iris %>% group_split(Species),
     y = list(1,10,100), 
     function(x,y)
       mutate(across(where(is.numeric), .x / .y)))

Error: unexpected ')' in "       mutate(across(where(is.numeric), .x / .y)))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version with `map2`:

```
map2(.x = iris %>% group_split(Species),
     .y = list(1,10,100), 
     function(x, div) {
       mutate(x, across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x / div))
      })
```

The main change is that `mutate()` needs a data frame to be its first argument, hence `mutate(x, ...)`. I've also renamed `y` to `div` to prevent confusion. We've got 2 anonymous functions... the `function(x, div)` means we have an argument `x` that is the data frame, and `div` that is each divisor. We give `x` to `mutate`, and then the second anonymous function (using the `~` notation) needs uses `.x` by default (for the numeric columns) but needs to use `div`, as it's inside the `(x, div)` function.

I don't really like the above code because it's relying on the `.y` list being in the same order as the `group_split` groups. If it were my code, I'd probably do it with a look-up table and join instead, which is safer because the relationship between the species and the divisor is now clear and checkable.

```
div = tribble(
  ~Species, ~factor,
  "setosa", 1,
  "versicolor", 10,
  "virginica", 100
)

iris %>% 
  left_join(div) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~.x / factor)) %>%
  select(-factor)
```

Comment: Thanks @gregor-thomas, this is excellent - agree the simple `left_join / mutate` is cleaner code, less chance of error mapping wrong factor to wrong data subset & the method I'll use. I was too map-minded - fresh eyes always helpful :)

And thanks for the explanation of the `map2` call, sorting `x` from `.x` inside the anonymous functions, in case I use it or similar in the future.